# Deactivate a JavaScript page-level event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class which I call via:

```
this.infiniteScroll = new gd.InfiniteScroll();
```

In this class it checks if user is at bottom of window.

Later on in my script I have no use for this infinite scroll script (as all data has been loaded). How can I delete it? or stop it from checking if user is at bottom of window?

Here's the infinite scroll class:

```
(function(){
"use strict";

var InfiniteScroll = function() {
    this.init();
};

var p = InfiniteScroll.prototype = gd.BaseClass.extend(gd.BaseClass);
p.BaseClass_init = p.init;

/*
 * Public properties
 */
p.canLoad = true;
p.cog;

/* 
 * Public methods
 */
p.init = function() {
    // Super
    this.BaseClass_init();

    // Init
    this.ready();

};

p.ready = function() {

    this._initInfiniteScroll();
};

p.loadRequested = function(){

    p.canLoad = false;
    console.log('show cog');
    $.event.trigger('loadRequested');

}

p.loadComplete = function(){

    p.canLoad = true;
    console.log('hide cog');
    console.log(p.canLoad);
}

p._initInfiniteScroll = function() {

    $(window).scroll(function(){  
        console.log('scroll!');
        if(($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) && p.canLoad){

            p.loadRequested();

        }  
    });   

}


gd.InfiniteScroll = InfiniteScroll;
}(window));
```

Comment: the answer will depend on whether the `gd.InfiniteScroll` class has the ability to detach itself from the page.

Comment: Does the library support it? Check the api.

Comment: @Yuck not remotely a duplicate

Comment: @Alnitak He's making a new reference to an object and wants to delete it later. Sounds identical.

Comment: @agconti Not a CSS class but an instance of a class - an object.

Comment: no, he's creating an object that is then automagically attaching itself to the DOM.  "Deleting" it will require that object to remove its event handlers, and any other reference to it, at which point it'll get GCed.

Comment: @panthro please attach a link to the documentation for that plugin

Comment: @Alnitak And that's all covered in the related question if you read through the responses.

Comment: It's not a plugin, it's a class I wrote. Will update original question with it.

Comment: Right, in which case you need to update that class with methods that allow it to de-register itself.  There's no need to "delete" the object, per se.

Comment: How would i go about de registering it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give your class a "deactivate" method that you can invoke as required:

```
p.deactivate = function() {
    $(window).off('scroll');
};
```

If you're utterly finished with the object you may also `delete this.infiniteScroll` to allow the garbage collector to reclaim the memory, but given how little memory this class takes there's little benefit in doing so.

NB: ideally you should "namespace" your event handlers so that you can deactivate your handlers independently of any others, e.g.:

```
$(window).on('scroll.infinite', ...);
```

and then subsequently:

```
$(window).off('scroll.infinite');
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Could you go in to a bit more detail about the namespacing. Im trying to integrate it with my code but it fails to work.

Comment: It's in the jQuery docs - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: downvoter, please explain?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you could just `delete this.infiniteScroll`. But I assume that in this case it actually attaches some event handlers, which means this isn't enough.

If the library is written well, you will probably have a method to detach all event handlers, a desctructor function or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying the plugin code, you can probably just do:

```
this.infiniteScroll.canLoad = false;
```

EDIT:

Now that I know it's your own code, you can simply keep track of your listener function and provide a destruction mechanism that will remove the listener.

```
p._initInfiniteScroll = function() {

    $(window).scroll(this._scrollHandler = function(){  
        console.log('scroll!');
        if(($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) && p.canLoad){

            p.loadRequested();

        }  
    });   

}

p.destroy = function () {
    $(window).off('scroll', this._scrollHandler);
    //you should probably call the destruction function of the parent class
    //if there's any.
};
```

Then just call `this.infiniteScroll.destroy();`

Comment: Yes, but then it will still check for this everytime the user scrolls.

Comment: @panthro True, but there's no other way without modifying the plugin.

Comment: It's not a plug in. It's code ive written so can mod it all I want.

Comment: @plalx I don't believe that's valid syntax for `.off` - you have to specify the event name, and (optionally) the event handler reference.

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah I corrected it already, careless mistake. It certainly did not deserve a downvote...

Comment: @plalx I didn't give you one, and if you're the one that downvoted my accepted answer because you believe I did then that's very petty.

Comment: That's natural, I got downvoted and my answer is similar to an upvoted one :P